# Without CONFIG_PREEMPT, kernel can't preempt?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I checked CentOS 8/Redhat 8, and Ubuntu 22.04, their default kernel setting for CONFIG_PREEMPT are all not set:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set
```

In my understanding, the kernel should be able to preempt by default. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a description of the `CONFIG_PREEMPT` configuration item [here](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PREEMPT.html), which says:

> This option reduces the latency of the kernel by making all kernel code (that is not executing in a critical section) preemptible. This allows reaction to interactive events by permitting a low priority process to be preempted involuntarily even if it is in kernel mode executing a system call and would otherwise not be about to reach a natural preemption point. This allows applications to run more 'smoothly' even when the system is under load, at the cost of slightly lower throughput and a slight runtime overhead to kernel code.

Normally, only user space code is preemptible. With `CONFIG_PREEMPT` enabled, then code executing in kernel space is *also* preemtible.

Comment: Thanks, I originally think both kernel and user space code can preempt.